# Prolog XPCE display predicate

Tags: prolog, predicate, assign, xpce

Hi I have program ("expert program") in which user choose few button options and this program search in predicates cars with this checked options. After this I wish to display this one or more predicates in window. This is few line of program. Predicates format:

```
auto(audi,a4,bialy,sedan,120).
```

`auto(audi,a6,czerwony,sedan,160).`

And fragment in which I wish display:

```
 X=auto(Marka,_,Kolor,Nadwozie,Km),
send(Cars,append(text(X))),
```

I am trying to assign the entire predicate to a variable, and I probably can not. How can I view this data in a different way?

EDIT:

I found class "findall()" which help a lot:

```
findall(Model,auto(Marka,Model,Kolor,Nadwozie,Km),X),
send(Cars,append(char_array(X))),
```

Now is ok, in console work, but not in XPCE, Prolog catch error in console:

ERROR: [Thread pce] char_array ->initialise: Argument 1 (text): `char_array' expected, found`[a2,a3]'

And what now? I think error is in "char_array(X)" but why this not work?

Comment: What do you mean by "display a predicate" or to "assign an entire predicate to a variable". A single predicate clause might be, for example, `foo(A, B) :- bar(A), gah(B).` and that could be assigned to a variable as `X = :-(foo(A,B), (bar(A), gah(B))).` You could then assert that predicate later via `assertz(X)`. But I suspect that's not what you really mean.

Comment: Did you mean "expert system" in place of "expert program"?

Comment: Yes false I mean expert system. lurker yes, you guessed my intentions, but I need show this variable as a result in new window

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
...
with_output_to(atom(X), write(auto(Marka,_,Kolor,Nadwozie,Km))),
send(Cars,append(text(X))),
...
```

Comment: this is correct in 50%, works but as result i have values which I choose in radio buttons, not this from matching predicates

Comment: it's show:
Auto choose for you:
auto(audi,_50,white,sedan,80-150)

but I wish this form for example:
Auto choose for you:
audi,a3,white,sedan,80